# How do I write an integer value to a csv file using opencsv

Tags: java, opencsv

This is my code for writing a csv file

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("test.csv",false));
String [] details = new String[]{"00000002","0","0","0","0","type_detils","01","1","-1","0.0","0.0","CST"};
writer.writeNext(details);
```

I want to write this value format in csv:

```
00000002,0,0,0,0,"type_detils",01,1,-1,0.0,0.0,"CST"
```

But when I look in the file it's like this:

```
"00000002","0","0","0","0","type_detils","01","1","-1","0.0","0.0","CST"
```

How can I change the string value to an integer during the file write using opencsv?

Comment: You can change CSV format while generating it if possible, I mean you can omit double quotes for numbers using settings..

Comment: Have you checked how `CSVWriter` (which package is it from?) is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the 3 param constructor ([link](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#CSVWriter(java.io.Writer,%20char,%20char))) like this:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("test.csv",false),',','\0');
```

Using the '\0' is the null char. Or perhaps pass null if the CSVWriter accepts it.

Comment: could you add a complete example of this? I don't get what you mean